# Installing Thrift PHP from RPM Failing

Tags: php, centos, thrift, rpm

I'm trying to install Thrift with PHP to my CentOS machine. Here's what I do and what goes wrong:

```
[root@x3430-20371 YACassandraPDO]# rpm -Uvh http://rpm.sys.fm/centos/6/x86_64/thrift-php-0.9.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://rpm.sys.fm/centos/6/x86_64/thrift-php-0.9.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        php(zend-abi) = 20090626 is needed by thrift-php-0.9.0-1.el6.x86_64
        php(api) = 20090626 is needed by thrift-php-0.9.0-1.el6.x86_64
[root@x3430-20371 YACassandraPDO]# php -v
PHP 5.4.25 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2014 14:20:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Maybe you guys have any ideas how to fix it. Thanks!

Also when I'm building from Thrift source, I get this error:

```
[root@x3430-20371 thrift]# ./bootstrap.sh
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
configure.ac:89: installing `./config.guess'
configure.ac:89: installing `./config.sub'
configure.ac:26: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac:26: installing `./missing'
compiler/cpp/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'
configure.ac: installing `./ylwrap'
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:178: variable `concurrency_test_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:178: library has `concurrency_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:187: variable `processor_test_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:187: library has `processor_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:195: variable `processor_test_LDADD' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:195: library has `processor_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:184: variable `concurrency_test_LDADD' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:184: library has `concurrency_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
[root@x3430-20371 thrift]#
```

Comment: IIRC there were some issues with CentOS because it is CentOS :-) - there are some very old packages around which cause trouble with Thrift. If you don't get an sufficient answer here on SO, asking on the mailing list and/or freenode may be another option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it, but can you point me to the right direction ?

Comment: What do you mean: the RPMs, the mailing list or freenode? The latter two can be found on the Thrift web site (http://thrift.apache.org/mailing), regarding the RPMs you will have to google the mailing list archives (links can be found on the same page)